# How to resolve 'Error 411- Content length required' in PHP with curl?

Tags: php, curl, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

[image]I am using google FCM to send the push notification to the Android device. Codeignitor is used at the server side.I am using the  [same code](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

But running via postman on localhost(XAMPP ver:5.6.28) getting the error `Error 411 (Length Required)!!1` .

I know this is an already asked question but those answers(set Content-Length:0) did not work for me.
How can I remove this error.Thanks in advance and sorry for my poor english

Comment: Set the `Content-Length` header using the length of your payload.

Comment: "*those answers did not work for me*" -- which answers?

Comment: @AL Setting Content-Length :0 did not worked for me

Comment: @Scuzzy  $headers = array('Authorization: key='.FIREBASE_API_KEY,'Content-Type:application/json','Content-Length:'.count($fields)); getting same error

Comment: Odd. I've used Postman to send messages, but `Content-Length` isn't supposed to be a requirement. Could you post a sample screenshot (removing the sensitive details)?

Comment: `count($‌​fields)` is going to be too short, you want a `strlen()` sourced value eg `strlen(json_encode($fields))` perhapps

Comment: @Scuzzy I tried this but same error

Comment: Your question deserves an upvote. @RahulKR, Did you find any solution brother?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 4 years late, but to fix the issue, you need to make sure there is no space in your key.

ex:

wrong:

```
Authorization: key=somekey (end space)
```

correct

```
Authorization: key=somekey(no space)
```